# SQL escape with sqlite in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, escaping

I have a text field and its breaking my sql statement. How do i escape all the chars in that field? I am using sqlite with http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ in C#

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should be using a parameter as in:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = @parameter";
cmd.Parameters.Add( new SQLiteParameter( "@parameter", textfield ) );
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Using a parametrised SQL will escape all input values and help protect you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What do i do if i have multiple params? do i write 
cmd.CommandText = "insert ... @parameter ... @parameter"; cmd.Parameters.Add(...);cmd.Parameters.Add(...); ?

Comment: Yes, there should also be an AddRange method available where you can pass an array of params that match the params in the sql statemenet.

Comment: You can call Parameters.Add multiple times just as you have asked or use the Parameters.AddRange which accepts an array of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace all single quote delimiters with  doubt single quotes (not ").

```
sql = sql.Replace("'","''");
```

Comment: This Method is not recommended, It may lead to strange bugs.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you build your SQL and make the Replace the last step, all should be good.  Worked for years without problems.  I use the Application Blocks now, so it doesn't matter. :)

Comment: this method is good if you need to create a SQL safe to dump to a text file or such.

Comment: Sometimes this method works when you build your queries dynamically.

Comment: Only use this method if you seriously want to lose your job. Not kidding here.