# Escaping SQL in C#/sqlite or: how can I use parameters here?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlparameter

I realize that handcrafting SQL statements is evil. I also realize that the spontaneous answer of everyone seeing this post will be "Use parameters". I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633245/sql-escape-with-sqlite-in-c-sharp) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261317/how-to-escape-a-string-in-system-data-sqlite) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599681/sqlite-issues-escaping-certain-characters) occurences of similar questions around here, but I can't find out how they apply to my specific problem.

I use `System.Data.SQLite` with C#. I want to dynamically create a VIEW, say `listview_asdf` which I then can access inside a library with simple `SELECT * FROM listview_asdf` statements. That library uses loads of automatically generated statements for accessing my view.

Problem is, at one point I need to create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW listview_asdf AS SELECT * FROM tbl_asdf WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

**not** knowing how many and which parameters I have in the `IN()` list. Actually, the list will be different each time I use it (I delete the views in their `Dispose()` methods). Creating the view does - as far as I understand [the relevant google result](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Parameters-are-not-allowed-in-views-td50403.html) - not allow to use parameters.

So, I need to take an arbitrary-length array of parameters (easy) and write the `CREATE VIEW` statement with an `IN (...)` clause. Here, I need to insert the parameter values. This is no problem in case of integers, as shown above, but for strings or other types (`System.DateTime` comes to mind) I need some kind of escaping.

Else, I need some way of getting around the necessity of escaping. I don't know of any solution to either except the ominous

```
sql = sql.Replace("'","''");
```

which, as [User Aur Saraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19993/aur-saraf) points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633245/sql-escape-with-sqlite-in-c-sharp#comment45396354_633271), is a sure way of losing my job (which I do like).

Any ideas for a way out?

Comment: `Replace` is to be avoid if there is a better way. Here, there is no better way.

Comment: Well, I guess I have to follow this advice. I hope this really prevents SQL injections (and if it does, why does everybody keep saying that it is evil? What are the drawbacks?). I must say I'm disappointed that C# doesn't offer an Escape function, citing the possibility to use parameters at every turn, leaving someone with my problem alone out in the wild. -1 for Microsoft here.