# InvalidOperationException: no current row error

Tags: c#, sqlite, authentication

I am getting this error on my login form. I am unsure on fixing it because I do not know what's wrong.

> InvalidOperationException: no current row

When I start the app, it crashes.

[image]

```
     private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = zivali_v2.sqlite");
         conn.Open();
         SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(conn);

         com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login;";

         SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

             string username = reader["username"].ToString();
             string password = reader["password"].ToString();

         bool loginValid = false;
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             if (username == textBoxUserName.Text && password == textBoxPassword.Text)
             {
                 loginValid = true;
                 break;

             }
         }

         if (loginValid)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("OK");
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
         }
         conn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Hey, what's up with your connection string?
`SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = zivali_v2.sqlite");`

Comment: What do you mean. Do you think my connection is the problem?

Comment: It may be, but it's strange that you aren't getting an error on the conn.open() function. What DB are you trying to connect to?

Comment: i am using SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

A reader object represents a query's result, which is shaped like a table, i.e., it has columns and rows.

An expression like `reader["username"]` reads the value in the specified column and in the *current* row. But before the first `Read()` call, there is no current row. This is what the error message is telling you.

You must not move the `reader["username"]` call out of the loop; you have to make a call in each loop iteration to get a new value from each row:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    username = reader["username"] ...
}
```

(And it would be a better idea to let the database use the comparisons, and to [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/633254/11654).)